# Updating ECS container without disclosing task definition environment variables

Tags: devops, amazon-ecs

I was looking at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/682340/update-the-container-of-a-service-in-amazon-ecs) on how to update a container of an ecs service. It requires me to pass in a JSON file with the task definition. My only worry is that if I have this on a CI/CD platform, I will have to commit my task definition, which contains secrets in the environment variables section.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the answers in that question are pretty off-base. I'll take some time later to write up a proper answer in that post. For now, I'm not sure what you're referring to by _pass in a JSON file with the task definition_. This definitely isn't a requirement from AWS, but is it something specific to your workflow? Can you elaborate a bit more on your specific scenario?

Comment: it was this line here that got me: `aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://$taskDefinitionFile --region $awsRegion > /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [AWS Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) and [chamber](https://github.com/segmentio/chamber) as described in this blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/the-right-way-to-store-secrets-using-parameter-store/

Briefly, the steps can be summarized as:

1. Install `chamber` locally where you can run it with suitable AWS privileges.
2. Create a KMS key named `parameter_store_key`.
3. Run `chamber write <service> <key> <value>` to add `key=value` into Parameter Store (`<service>` is a label for your application).
4. Assign your ECS Task an IAM Role that has permission to access the Parameter Store parameter and KMS key.
5. Install `chamber` into your docker image.
6. Update the `ENTRYPOINT` of your docker image to run `chamber exec <service> -- yourapp`.
7. The Parameter Store parameters for `<service>` will now be available to your app in the environment.